# onLayoutChange() not called

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a custom view

```
 abstract public class MyView extends AdapterView<Adapter> implements android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
     ...
     @Override
     public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
         Log.i("MyView", "onLayoutChange()");
     }
 }
```

an anonymous subclass of which I instantiate and set as my ContentView during `onResume()`

```
onResume() {
    ...
    MyView myView = new MyView(this) {...};
    setContentView(myView);
}
```

When I now hide the `ActionBar` and switch to full screen with

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getActionBar().hide();
```

the `ActionBar` and the status bar slowly shrink until they are no longer visible as intended.

Now my `MyView` would in principle have more space on the screen, but as far as I can tell it is not automatically re-measured and layouted to fill this space.

I would have expected that at least the `onLayoutChange()` method is called, but I can see with logcat that this is **not** the case.

What do I need to do in order that `onLayoutChange()` is called in this situation or how else can I tell my `MyView` to fill the available space?

Comment: did you call addOnLayoutChangeListener ?

Comment: Thanks. I am feeling really stupid now. That's it.

Comment: come on, it even happens to the best devs...;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give this question an answer (or you can answer it yourself with your own code) ...

As @pskink noted in the comments, don't forget to call `addOnLayoutChangeListener`.